# Checking which date is closest to today

Tags: arrays, swift, nsdate

I have an array of NSDates that I want to be able to check through each one and put in order of which one is closest to today.

Is there any method or function for doing this? So for example this is my dates:

```
var dateArr = ["2015-11-08", "2015-11-09", "2015-11-10"]
```

I now want to iterate through them and put them in order of closest date to current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have NSDates in an array. I used this code to create the dates array:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let d1 = cal.dateFromComponents(
    {
        let comp = NSDateComponents()
        comp.year = 2015
        comp.month = 11
        comp.day = 8
        return comp
    }())

let d2 = cal.dateFromComponents(
    {
        let comp = NSDateComponents()
        comp.year = 2015
        comp.month = 11
        comp.day = 9
        return comp
    }())

let d3 = cal.dateFromComponents({
    let comp = NSDateComponents()
    comp.year = 2015
    comp.month = 11
    comp.day = 6
    return comp
    }())

let dates = [d1!,d2!,d3!]
```

The sorting itself I do with

```
var today:NSDate?
// creates an date at the beginning an given time unit, here Day
cal.rangeOfUnit(.Day, startDate: &today, interval: nil, forDate: NSDate())

let sortedDates = dates.sort { (d1, d2) -> Bool in
    var t1 = abs(d1.timeIntervalSinceDate(today!))
    var t2 = abs(d2.timeIntervalSinceDate(today!))
    return t1 <= t2
}

print(sortedDates)
```

Comment: Thank you this is a better answer after further research

Answer (score 6):

If you want to sort array with `NSDate` objects in order of closest date to current date, you can do it like this:

```
let toodayUnixTime = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
// array with `NSDate` objects
var dates = [...]
// Sort action
dates.sortInPlace({ abs($0.timeIntervalSince1970 - toodayUnixTime) < abs($1.timeIntervalSince1970 - toodayUnixTime) })
```

In this case we have `dates` array with `NSDate`. The first object of sorted array is the closest to current date.

Comment: Thanks although these are NSDate objects in 'dateArr', I have displayed them as strings so you can actually see the different dates, sorry my fault I think! I just need to be able to sort the NSDate elements inside the array to be in order of closest to the current date. Does your answer do this?

Comment: these are not sorted for today but now. That will lead to different results.

Comment: @HenryBrown do this for example to get current day ` let toodayUnixTime = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))!.timeIntervalSince1970`

Comment: Hi @alex_p I have found this this does not work if taking into account the current date. so if the current date is inside the array it will come out second for some reason? Please could you advice further?

Comment: @HenryBrown From what you wrote, I did not understand what the problem is